# Not generate Binding file

Tags: android, android-databinding

Android Studio 3.1.

app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
}
```

name of xml file: **preview_brand_item.xml**

In my adapter:

```
import com.myproject.android.customer.databinding.PreviewBrandItemBinding;

public class PreviewBrandSortAdapter extends PreviewBaseSortAdapter {

@Override
    protected int getLayoutIdForPosition(int position) {
        return R.layout.preview_brand_item;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setClickHandler(ViewDataBinding binding) {
        PreviewBrandItemBinding previewBrandItemBinding = (PreviewBrandItemBinding) binding;
        previewBrandItemBinding.setClickHandler(this);
}
}
```

Here parent adapter:

```
public abstract class PreviewBaseSortAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter {

@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, viewType, parent, false);
        setClickHandler(binding);
        return new PreviewBaseViewHolder(binding);
}

}
```

But **PreviewBrandItemBinding** is not generate and as result I get error:

```
myproject\app\src\main\java\com\myproject\android\customer\ui\adapter\PreviewBrandSortAdapter.java:17: error: package com.myproject.android.customer.databinding does not exist
import com.myproject.android.customer.databinding.PreviewBrandItemBinding;
```